# How to prevent an application from being uninstalled

Tags: android, uninstallation, password-protection

I have requirement in my Project i.e  prevent application uninstall using password.is it possible, if yes could you suggest how it is.

Comment: What a terrible requirement...

Answer (score 2):

May this Help you

I think the closest thing to what your looking for is the `Device Administration` feature introduced in 2.2.

Once the application is registered as a Device Administrator, it can't be uninstalled unless its unregistered. This will prevent the app from being uninstalled.

While the Device Admin API doesn't allow for password protection of this particular feature, you can password protect your application to prevent someone from tampering with the Device Admin features in the app.

**OR:**

You can make your application as `System Application`.. But for that you need to `Root` your Device first....

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible on Android for security reasons.

Comment: your answer is okay but describe more so user can understand easily why the they can't do and what.:)